# How to reference and use same class library in two WebApps in single solution file?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a single solution file that has two `asp.netmvcWebs` called `AspnetMvcWebApp1` and `AspnetMvcWebAp2`.

After I created new class library called `BuinessFunctionalityClassLibrary` in the same solution file, the solution includes `AspnetMvcWebApp1`, `AspnetMvcWebAp2` and `BuinessFunctionalityClassLibrary`.

I want to reference and use `BuinessFunctionalityClassLibrary` in both my WebApps, `AspnetMvcWebApp1` and `AspnetMvcWebAp2`. The idea is: If I want to add any functionality to my program I need just modify `BuinessFunctionalityClassLibrary`.
Is it doable? If so how can this be achieved?

My environment: Visual Studio 2017 and C#, Asp.NEN MVC5 and .NET Framework 4.7.

Comment: Create a new project for your library and include it in your solution. Then add the project reference to your web apps.

Comment: before asking, you should have tried it once

Comment: Hello auburg, i alredy tried that i am getting "error CS0234: The type or namespace name "xx" does not exist in the namespace 'YYY' (are you missing an assembly reference" though i am referenceing the class library and also using correct name space in the controller of webapp2

Comment: this is solved. issue was classliobrary .net fraework was 4.7.X and web app .net framewrok version was 4.6.X, once i upgraded webapp to frame work 4.7.X, it worked